# Question about alternating commands every minute in Cron

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, cron, playonlinux

I've been editing my crontab with `crontab -e -u`, and this is the contents:

```
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force off 

*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force on
```

How do I make the on time holding for 1 minute, so the display is off for 1 minute then on 1 minute?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3

Comment: still the same ...

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to make my display off 1 minute then on 1 minute.... but now its able to off after 1 minute... but not able to on for another 1 minute ...its will on awhile like 1 sec then turn back to off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want crontab lines that execute a command at alternating minutes, like the first command at even minutes (0,2,4 etc.) and the second command at odd minutes (1,3,5 etc.).

This can be done in the following way:

```
0-59/2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force off 

1-59/2 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && xset dpms force on
```

**Explanation**:

The minute entry here makes use of 2 different elements - *ranges* and *step values*.

The *range* has the format `?-?`, so we define two different ranges, starting 1 minute apart (`0-59` and `1-59`).

The `/2` part is the *step value*. By using this, we tell cron to only execute at *every other* value in the range.

By using the full possible minute range (but different starting values), we ensure that the commands run at every alternating minute, but 1 minute apart.

**Fun fact**:

The first range could also be entered as `0-58` and it wouldn't make a difference (since odd values are skipped in this range).

Comment: Wow!!thank you ....its work thank you thank you

Comment: You're welcome! :-) Please mark the answer as accepted with the green tick mark. Thanks.